# how to solve Duplication class error in android studio

Tags: android, class, android-studio

I am a beginner in Android Development . How to solve duplicate class Error in android studio ? The error is something like duplicate

`class: com.example.android;countscore.R`

[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Tfxr.png)

Comment: post your gradle, and libs folder details

Comment: can you please tell me how to open gradle and libs details ? I am a beginner and i don't know much about android studio ..

Answer (score 1):

You should probably go to the dropdown menu and clean your build. Most of the time the errors with .R will disappear when you clean your build.

If this doesn't work you probably have 2 different R.java files in different directories. Search and locate those and delete them. Then rebuild. This should do the trick. I recommend trying the first solution before doing the second solution.